# How to use a shared .py file across multiple workflows in FME?

Tags: python, fme-form, fme-transformer

I have a python methods "toto" that I would like to use in multiple FeatureProcessors of multiple workflows.

In FME (2023) options O added a new shared folder
[image]

and put there my python file (FME generated some default directories)
[image]

however, it does not seem to take it into consideration

```
import fme
import fmeobjects
import re
import shared_methods

class FeatureProcessor(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def split_address(self, feature):
```

it says:

> Python Exception : No module named 'shared_methods'

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the shared_methods.py fine in the correct location and with the correct strategies for shared_methods.py to be visible to the Python interpreter.  [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-do-i-import-other-python-files) for more help.

Comment: surely that Correctly using Correct things we can obtain Correct results. That philosophy is good, however, OP asked a practical question, is better to use explanation than links, links could be broken in future. The question is not about python, as I don't use it outside FME, so FME is my only interface to python.

Comment: @serge - True, I voted to close since this is a Python management and practices question with no GIS component.  Hopefully the user will see the link, and find help before the question is closed by the community.